# Is the stochastic gradient descent minimization implemented in Mathematica?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to use Stochastic Gradient Descent method on its own (not for neural networks) to minimize an objective function in Mathematica. I couldn't find any SGD routine implemented in Mathematica (12.0) so far. Is it an option in one of the routines?
Thanks.

Comment: `FindMinimum` uses a gradient for its various methods, but I haven't seen _stochastic_ gradient descent there. Probably when a full gradient is available it's not that effective compared to the others. You'd normally use SGD for parameter estimation / regression, when the cost surface is unavailable but you have an approx gradient at random sample points. In any case, here's a Wolfram Demonstrations Project notebook from 2011 https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/StochasticGradientDescent/ . There's also `BayesianMinimization` which can minimize non-deterministic functions if that interests you.

Comment: @flinty, in my case the cost function is exactly in the form of first equation in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent and SGD seems a very suitable method to minimize this function. My problem has not come from neural network. So even though the neural network related commands in Mathematica uses SGD, I don't know how to use this method for my own function.

Comment: @dbm It could be better to show your function and your attempt to minimize it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to piggyback off the neural network functionality which is doing some form of SGD internally, at least if you have `FunctionLayer` which was introduced in v12.2

In this particular example, I use `NetTrain` to find a root of $x^5/6 - 2 x^3 - x^2 + 4$ by minimization of its absolute value.

Here we start with a vector of random guesses `guess`. The network trains by overfitting the weights in the `LinearLayer`. The training data is just one sample `{guess -> 0}`.

After it has trained we take the `guess` vector, apply the `LinearLayer` to it, and select the value which best minimizes `f`.

```
f = x |-> Abs[x^5/6 - 2 x^3 - x^2 + 4];
guessCount = 1;
guess = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, guessCount];
net = NetChain[{LinearLayer[guessCount, "Input" -> guessCount], 
    ElementwiseLayer[f], FunctionLayer[Min]}];
net = NetInitialize[net];
net = NetTrain[net, {guess -> 0}, TargetDevice -> "GPU", 
  MaxTrainingRounds -> 20000]
xsol = First@MinimalBy[NetTake[net, 1][guess], f]
(* 1.14669 *)

f[xsol]
(* 3.31321*10^-10 *)
```

This method could be extended to multivariate problems. As long as you can express your objective in the `FunctionLayer` *(this is not always possible and not all Mathematica functions are allowed)*. You can add *penalty* terms to the objective, e.g `... + 10000 UnitStep[x - 1]` for $x\ge1$ to discourage solutions outside your constraints. *(unfortunately `Boole` doesn't work)*